# Set the IplImage->imageData in JavaCV

Tags: java

I would like to set the variable imagedata of IplImage.
just like

```
rightImage.imageData[(j * leftImage.width() + i) * leftImage.nChannels() + k] = (unsigned char)255;
```

Now I would like to use the JavaCV, how can i set the image